# Join/Link by date-time attribute

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, time, geotag

Using QGIS 2.14 I would need to join/link multiple layers with each a couple of hundred records with a georeferenced point layer - so basically much like geotagging of pictures.

Do you have any idea on how to link the xyz-less records to the most nearest geographical record, both based on the Date-Time attribute ?

I don't speak Python

Comment: is the date-time attribute unique? or do you have multiple entries per geo point?

Comment: Both might and could be, even though I wouldnt suggest so.

Answer (score 2):

You had better to upload your date into a database e.g. PostgreSQL/PostGIS and use SQL to find nearest in time. I give you a simple example, table "first" has two columns id1 (primary key), d1 date-time value, table "second" also has two columns id2 (primary key), d2 date-time value. You may have other columns in any tables.
The query to find nearest pairs in time:

```
with dif as (
    select first.id1, min(GREATEST(first.d1,second.d2)-LEAST(first.d1,second.d2)) as mindif
    from first, second
    group by first.id1
)
select first.id1, second.id2, first.d1-second.d2 as dd
from first, second
where GREATEST(first.d1,second.d2)-LEAST(first.d1,second.d2) = (select mindif from dif where id1 = first.id1)
```

Some explanation:
the first select creates the minimal difference to the rows in the first table to the second table. The min(GREATEST(first.d1,second.d2)-LEAST(first.d1,second.d2)) creates the absolute value of time differences, there is no direct function for it.
Th second select finds the id2 from the second table. The query result will be id1,id2 and the time difference.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying with SQLite, but there are no GREATEST or LEAST functions, just min() and max().

Comment: SQLite has multi arguments min and max functions, which you can use instead of PostgreSQL GREATEST and LEAST functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166690/sqlite-equivilant-of-postgresqls-greatest-function